# How to filter JSON values with jq command?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have the below JSON file

```
{
    "0": {
        "data_bags": {
            "license_keys": {
                "nagios": "xxx"
            },
            "passwords": {
                "ONE": "abcd",
                "TWO": "efgh",
                "THREE": "hhhhh",
                "FOUR": "abcdefgh"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to display password's with the help of `jq` command. Can someone please help?

tried with below cmd:

```
cat .\sample.json | jq-win64.exe -r ".0.data_bags.passwords.license_keys.ONE"
```

getting below error

```
jq: error: Invalid numeric literal at EOF at line 1, column 3 (while parsing '.0.') at <top-level>, line 1:
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines, e.g, what output exactly are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part is you can't use `.0` as it's interpreted as a number, you need to use quotes:

```
jq '."0".data_bags.passwords | keys' file.json
```

Comment: This is still giving same error @choroba.

Comment: Ouch, you're on MSWin! I have no idea how quoting works there, maybe you need `".\"0\".data_bags.passwords | keys"` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps use `..`, e.g. along the lines of:

```
.. | objects | .passwords // empty
```